# How can one declare and set a variable in a MySQL call (and linked to by) SQL Server stored precedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to set a variable in SQL Server and pass it to MySQL and access it using the "?"'s.

However, I want to embed a declare and set variable in my sql text that I'm passing to MySQL.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. How are you using both SQL-Server and MySQL together?

Comment: You should try to improve your question by adding some part of your code.